# Iteratively and hierarchically cycle through rows till a condition is met

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, data-manipulation, tidyr

I'm trying to solve a data management problem in R.

Suppose my data looks as follows:

```
id <- c("123", "414", "606")
next.up <- c("414", "606", "119")
is.cond.met <- as.factor(c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"))
df <- data.frame(id, next.up, is.cond.met)

> df
   id next.up is.cond.met
1 123     414       FALSE
2 414     606       FALSE
3 606     119        TRUE
```

And I'd like to obtain is the following:

```
id <- c("123", "414", "606")
next.up <- c("414", "606", "119")
is.cond.met <- as.factor(c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE"))
origin <- c("606", "606", "119")
df.result <- data.frame(id, next.up, is.cond.met, origin)

> df.result
   id next.up is.cond.met origin
1 123     414       FALSE    606
2 414     606       FALSE    606
3 606     119        TRUE    119
```

In other words: I want to match each ID to its "origin" when a given condition (is.met) is true. The difficulty I'm having is that this is iterative and hierarchical: to find the origin I may have to go through multiple degrees of separations. the logical steps are illustrated below. I'm really not sure how to tackle this in R.

[image: logical steps]

**UPDATE**
One of the comments propose a data.frame solution which works for sorted data, as in the minimal example above.  In truth, my data is not sorted in such a manner. A better example is as follows:

```
id <- c("961980", "14788", "902460", "900748", "728912", "141726", "1041190", "692268")
next.up <- c("20090", "655036", "40375164", "40031850", "40368996", "961980", "141726", "760112")
is.cond.met <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
df <- data.frame(id, next.up, is.cond.met, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

glimpse(df)

Observations: 8
Variables: 3
$ id          <chr> "961980", "14788", "902460", "900748", "728912", "141726", "1041190", "692268"
$ next.up     <chr> "20090", "655036", "40375164", "40031850", "40368996", "961980", "141726", "760112"
$ is.cond.met <lgl> TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
> df
       id  next.up is.cond.met
1  961980    20090        TRUE
2   14788   655036       FALSE
3  902460 40375164       FALSE
4  900748 40031850       FALSE
5  728912 40368996       FALSE
6  141726   961980       FALSE
7 1041190   141726       FALSE
8  692268   760112       FALSE
```

**UPDATE 2**: *the end result should look like this:*

```
> df.end.result
       id  next.up is.cond.met origin
1  961980    20090        TRUE   <NA>
2   14788   655036       FALSE   <NA>
3  902460 40375164       FALSE   <NA>
4  900748 40031850       FALSE   <NA>
5  728912 40368996       FALSE   <NA>
6  141726   961980       FALSE 961980
7 1041190   141726       FALSE 961980
8  692268   760112       FALSE   <NA>
```

Comment: Can you add a few more rows to the example? I"m not sure I'm following the logic

Comment: Are you trying to match entries from 2 different data set? That's the only sense I can try to make out of this. If that is the case, it might be helpful to make that explicit.

Comment: @BryanGoggin No. the data is as in df. df.result only shows what I would like the end result to look like.

Comment: If there is a gap in the data as you mentioned in the updated example what should the result be? Should the algorithm search for the next.up only in the next row or in all the following rows? And if the next.up cannot be found what should the algorithm do?

Comment: @George91 It should search in all the following (and/or previous) rows. If no match is found, origin==NA

Comment: If you want to do this efficiently, you should probably store your data in a tree structure (next.up being the "parent" to a given node) and use an algo to traverse. I'm no computer scientist and so don't know precisely the best tool, but this looks promising: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html Of course, this assumes that your data has a modicum of sanity (no next.up loops, no repeating id rows).

Answer (score 5):

I have extended your example data a bit to show what happens with more `TRUE` values in `is.cond.met`. Using the `data.table` package, you could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := shift(cumsum(is.cond.met), fill=0)
          ][, origin := ifelse(is.cond.met, next.up, id[.N]), by = grp][]
```

which gives:

```
> df
    id next.up is.cond.met grp origin
1: 123     414       FALSE   0    606
2: 414     606       FALSE   0    606
3: 606     119        TRUE   0    119
4: 119     321       FALSE   1    321
5: 321     507        TRUE   1    507
6: 507     185        TRUE   2    185
```

*Explanation:*

1. Create a grouping variable first with `shift(cumsum(is.cond.met), fill=0)`.
2. With `ifelse(is.cond.met, next.up, id[.N])` you assign the correct values to `origin`.

*Note:* The `id` and `next.up` columns should be of class character for the above to work (for that reason I used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in constructing the extended example data). If they are factors, convert them first with `as.character`. If `is.cond.met` isn't already a logical, convert it with `as.logical`.

---

On the updated example data, the above code gives:

```
        id  next.up is.cond.met grp origin
1:  961980    20090        TRUE   0  20090
2:   14788   655036       FALSE   1 692268
3:  902460 40375164       FALSE   1 692268
4:  900748 40031850       FALSE   1 692268
5:  728912 40368996       FALSE   1 692268
6:  141726   961980       FALSE   1 692268
7: 1041190   141726       FALSE   1 692268
8:  692268   760112       FALSE   1 692268
```

---

Used data:

```
id <- c("123", "414", "606", "119", "321", "507")
next.up <- c("414", "606", "119", "321", "507", "185")
is.cond.met <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)

df <- data.frame(id, next.up, is.cond.met, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks.  While adapting the code to the real data, I get the following error: 

`Type of RHS ('character') must match LHS ('integer'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)`

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel Did you convert the columns as I said in the ***note***?

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel What is the result of `sapply(df, class)`?

Comment: I did.  `> sapply(df.test, class)
         id      next.up      is.cond.met         grp      origin
"character" "character"   "logical"   "integer"   "integer" `

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel Could you include a sample of your real data in the question? (preferably the output of for example `dput(head(df.test, 10))`)

Comment: for some reasons the code works if I filter the original data. But produces the wrong "origin" when I do not filter it.  Does sort order matter in the data.table approach provided?

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel As a result of the way you presented the example data, the order does matter in the approach I've given above. If you can't share (a part of) your real data, could you construct an example dataset the better mimics your real data and problem? Without an example that reproduces the problem, it is quite a lot harder to say how to solve this.

Comment: thanks. It's hard to capture the data idiosyncrasies while preserving confidentiality, maximizing brevity and clarity ;-).  My data is not sorted.  I have edited the question to include a better example.

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I've included the output of my code on the updated example. Could you indicate whether this is the output you expected? If that is not the case, could you indicate in which rows it should give a different result (and in what way)?

Comment: I've included another update with what it should look like

Answer (score 3):

So, imho, I think you cannot solve it without an interative update.

Similar to @procrastinatus-maximus here is an iterative solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dfIterated <- data.frame(df, cond.origin.node = id, 
                         cond.update = is.cond.met, stringsAsFactors = F)
initial.cond <- dfIterated$is.cond.met
while(!all(dfIterated$is.cond.met %in% c(TRUE, NA))) {
  dfIterated <- dfIterated %>% 
    mutate(cond.origin.node = if_else(is.cond.met,
                                      cond.origin.node, 
                                      next.up),
           parent.match = match(next.up, id),
           cond.update = (cond.update[parent.match] | cond.update),
           cond.origin.node = if_else(!is.cond.met & cond.update,
                                      next.up[parent.match],
                                      next.up),
           is.cond.met = cond.update)
}
# here we use ifelse instead of if_else since it is less type strict
dfIterated %>%
  mutate(cond.origin.node = ifelse(initial.cond,  
                                   yes = NA, 
                                   no  = cond.origin.node))
```

*edit*: added starting condition; replaced `ifelse` by `dplyr::if_else`

---

**Explanation**: We iteratively update the `dfIterated` to include all `next.up` nodes as already suggested. Here we do it for every `id` in parallel.

1. We mutate `cond.origin.node` and replace it by the id if `cond.is.met == TRUE` and with `next.up` "otherwise" - `NA` values in `cond.is.met` will return `NA` values themselfes, which is very pratical in our case.

   - We then compute the matching parent index
2. We update the `cond.update` where we match the parent in the `id` column. (Values which will return NA, i.e., there are no matches in `id`, will be replaced by `NA`.) And we use `|` (or) operator which fortunetaley will return `TRUE == (TRUE | NA)` if there is previous `TRUE` entry in `cond.update`
3. We then need to compute the originating node for the `TRUE` condition.
4. And then upde the condition in `is.cond.met`
5. Repeat everything till our `is.cond.met` consists solely of `TRUE`s or `NA`s. The orgin will contain nodes for which the `cond.is.met == TRUE`

---

The output of the above example looks like this:

```
> dfIterated
       id  next.up is.cond.met cond.origin.node cond.update
1  961980    20090        TRUE             <NA>        TRUE
2   14788   655036          NA             <NA>          NA
3  902460 40375164          NA             <NA>          NA
4  900748 40031850          NA             <NA>          NA
5  728912 40368996          NA             <NA>          NA
6  141726   961980        TRUE           961980        TRUE
7 1041190   141726        TRUE           961980        TRUE
8  692268   760112          NA             <NA>          NA
```

Hope this helps! A forward lookup would work in similar fashion. Further improvements depend on what kind of results you want to keep (e.g. do you really want to overwrite `is.cond.met` ?)

Comment: this is almost what I want, except row 1 should evaluate to missing because as soon as the condition is met, **origin** should not evaluate to **next.up**. See my update. That should be trivial to fix. My data is huge, so I hope this approach is fast! I will test on the real data and will report back.

Comment: Interestingly it is not that *trivial* to fix :-) since it would break the assumptions for the algorithm -- but luckely we can store it in the beginning and replace the origin at the end accordingly. (Edits made in the code). The additional storage complexity is in O(2n) since we just require 3+3 additional columns - that mean that if you load you < 10GB file expect roughly 20GB result. Single operations should be fast, they are already vectorized (consider using `dplyr::if_else` for faster processing instead of `ifelse`. The algorithm should stop after the deepest node has been reached.

Comment: btw if you data is more than 10 GB you can switch to data.table. It will be definetly faster - the principle will remain the same but the syntax will be different.

Comment: Update: I'm still having problems with the code proposed. It works fine in the example. However, it does not work as expected on the real data. I'm struggling to understand why.

Comment: Since the bounty is about to expire, I will award it to @Drey, since his solution gets me the closest to what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! Can you describe in more detail what is troubling you with the real data ?

Answer (score 3):

I hope I've understood your problem correctly and here follows my point of view. It seems like you try to solve a network problem in terms of tables of data. I suggest the following formulation.

We have a network, defined as a set of edges (columns `id` and `next.up` correspond to `vertex_from` and `vertex_to`). The network is a set of trees. Column `is.cond.met` maps vertices which are endpoints or the roots of the trees. Trees with unmapped root aren't taken into account.

I've slightly modified your MRE to make it more demonstrative.

```
id <- c("961980", "14788", "902460", "900748", "728912", "141726", "1041190", "692268", "40368996", "555555", "777777")
next.up <- c("20090", "655036", "40375164", "40031850", "40368996", "961980", "141726", "760112", "692268", "760112", "555555")
is.cond.met <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
dt <- data.table(id, next.up, is.cond.met, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now lets translate everything to the language of graphs.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(igraph)

graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(dt[, 1:2, with = F])) -> dt_graph
V(dt_graph)$color <- ifelse(V(dt_graph)$name %in% dt[is.cond.met == T]$next.up, "green", "yellow")
E(dt_graph)$arrow.size <- .7
E(dt_graph)$width <- 2
plot(dt_graph, edge.color = "grey50")
```

We have the following graph.
[image]

Green vertices are mapped roots - let's name them treeroots. Their neghbors of the fisrt order are the roots of the big main branches of each tree - let them be branchroots. The problem is for every vertex in `id` column of initial data find out corresponding branchroot.

```
treeroots <- dt[is.cond.met == T]$next.up %>% unique
lapply(V(dt_graph)[names(V(dt_graph)) %in% treeroots], 
       function(vrtx) neighbors(dt_graph, vrtx, mode = "in")) -> branchroots
```

We can find all vertices downlaying to each branchroot with the help of `ego` function from `igraph` package.

```
lapply(seq_along(branchroots), function(i) {
  data.table(tree_root = names(branchroots[i]), branch_root = branchroots[[i]]$name)
}) %>% rbindlist() -> branch_dt

branch_dt[, trg_vertices := ego(dt_graph, order = 1e9, 
                                V(dt_graph)[names(V(dt_graph)) %in% branch_dt$branch_root], 
                                mode = "in", mindist = 1) %>% lapply(names)]

branch_dt
#    tree_root branch_root    trg_vertices
# 1:     20090      961980  141726,1041190
# 2:    760112      692268 40368996,728912
# 3:    760112      555555          777777
```

After that we can create the `origin` column.

```
sapply(seq_along(branch_dt$branch_root), 
       function(i) rep(branch_dt$branch_root[i], 
                       length(branch_dt$trg_vertices[[i]]))) %>% unlist -> map_vertices
branch_dt$trg_vertices %>% unlist() -> map_names
names(map_vertices) <- map_names

dt[, origin := NA_character_]
dt[id %in% map_names, origin := map_vertices[id]]
dt
#           id  next.up is.cond.met origin
#  1:   961980    20090        TRUE     NA
#  2:    14788   655036       FALSE     NA
#  3:   902460 40375164       FALSE     NA
#  4:   900748 40031850       FALSE     NA
#  5:   728912 40368996       FALSE 692268
#  6:   141726   961980       FALSE 961980
#  7:  1041190   141726       FALSE 961980
#  8:   692268   760112        TRUE     NA
#  9: 40368996   692268       FALSE 692268
# 10:   555555   760112       FALSE     NA
# 11:   777777   555555       FALSE 555555
```

For the sake of convenience, I've arranged the resulting code into a function.

```
add_origin <- function(dt) {
  require(data.table)
  require(magrittr)
  require(igraph)

  setDT(dt)
  graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(dt[, .(id, next.up)])) -> dt_graph

  treeroots <- dt[is.cond.met == T]$next.up %>% unique

  lapply(V(dt_graph)[names(V(dt_graph)) %in% treeroots], 
         function(vrtx) neighbors(dt_graph, vrtx, mode = "in")) -> branchroots

  lapply(seq_along(branchroots), function(i) {
    data.table(tree_root = names(branchroots[i]), branch_root = branchroots[[i]]$name)
  }) %>% rbindlist() -> branch_dt

  branch_dt[, trg_vertices := rep(list(NA), nrow(branch_dt))][]
  vertices_on_branch <- ego(dt_graph, order = 1e9, 
                            V(dt_graph)[names(V(dt_graph)) %in% branch_dt$branch_root], 
                            mode = "in", mindist = 1) %>% lapply(names)
  set(branch_dt, j = "trg_vertices", value = list(vertices_on_branch))

  sapply(seq_along(branch_dt$branch_root),
         function(i) rep(branch_dt$branch_root[i], 
                         length(branch_dt$trg_vertices[[i]]))) %>% unlist -> map_vertices
  branch_dt$trg_vertices %>% unlist() -> map_names
  names(map_vertices) <- map_names

  dt[, origin := NA_character_]
  dt[id %in% map_names, origin := map_vertices[id]]
  dt[]
}
```

For your MRE it produces the desired output.

```
df0 <- data.frame(id = c("961980", "14788", "902460", "900748", "728912", "141726", "1041190", "692268"),
                  next.up = c("20090", "655036", "40375164", "40031850", "40368996", "961980", "141726", "760112"),
                  is.cond.met = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df0 %>% add_origin

#         id  next.up is.cond.met origin
# 1:  961980    20090        TRUE     NA
# 2:   14788   655036       FALSE     NA
# 3:  902460 40375164       FALSE     NA
# 4:  900748 40031850       FALSE     NA
# 5:  728912 40368996       FALSE     NA
# 6:  141726   961980       FALSE 961980
# 7: 1041190   141726       FALSE 961980
# 8:  692268   760112       FALSE     NA
```

The described approach should be significantly faster than iterative update of a `data.frame` inside a loop.